# Why is g++ Giving Me Conflicting Errors While Compiling?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, cin

I am attempting to compile my second, (still noobish) C++ program, and g++ is giving me these errors:

```
new.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
new.cpp:10:4: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
    cin >> name;
```

is the first. Here's the second:

```
    ^~~
new.cpp:10:4: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from new.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/iostream:60:18: note:   ‘std::cin’
   extern istream cin;  /// Linked to standard input
                  ^~~
```

and I believe these are telling me to change both ways to write it to the other. I have tried changing both, and I'm not sure how to fix this. Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
 std::string age;
 std::string name;
    std::cout << "Please input your age.";
   std::cin >> age;
    std::cout << "Please input your name.";
   cin >> name;
    return 0;
}
```

**(CLOSED)**

Comment: Why do you use `std::cin` one time and `cin` the second time?

Comment: You need `std::cin >> name;` instead of `cin >> name;`;

Comment: It was just me seeing what the error messages would say. idk why they both got an error.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ but one is like that, and it still got errors.

Comment: @user14665036 [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bb176ce5a591034), sorry.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ what does that mean?

Comment: @user14665036 click the link and see what's there.

Comment: You've only provided **one** error.  The "second" is not an error, it is a **note**.

Comment: The second part means "Note that you might be able to fix the previously mentioned error by writing 'std::cin' instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little bit of explanation for a c++ and g++ newbie:

> `new.cpp:10:4: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope`

`cin` is declared under the `std` namespace. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin

The second one is not an error, but a suggestion by the compiler by pointing to the alternative found by the compiler. It gives a hint about `std::cin`.

```
note: suggested alternative:
In file included from new.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/iostream:60:18: note:   ‘std::cin’
   extern istream cin;  /// Linked to standard input
                  ^~~
```

At line 10, you are using `cin` from the global namespace. Therefore, the compiler complains that it can't find the declaration of `cin`.

Our fellow already provided a fix for you by changing line 10 to: `std::cin >> name;`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string age;
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Please input your age.";
    std::cin >> age;
    std::cout << "Please input your name.";
    std::cin >> name;
    return 0;
}
```